# What is this white device?

Tags: antenna, camera, transmitter, device

I know this question might sound a little silly and this is probably not the best site to ask, but I would really appreciate any answer. My neighbours installed this device just opposite to windows of my appartment:

[image: white device]

It is white and I can see a tiny blue light on it in the night.

I hope it must be some kind of antenna, but I googled a lot a did not find anything. It also may be a camera, which makes me feel quite uncomfortable and that is why I ask this question... You know: *Just because I'm paranoid doesn't mean they're not out to get me* :-).

Comment: WiFi range extender

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't know them and I don't know their language...

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a BB gun on it then LOL

Comment: Can you give an Image with less Detail and more irrelevant surroundings?

Comment: @JonRB - you seem sure..what model #? I'd also suggest a radio device (could be GPS too). Vojta, you **know** that you'll sleep uneasy 'till you're sure it isn't an alien "phone home" device. What a great way to introduce yourself to new neighbours!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where you live, but in Europe there are a number of free wireless networks. My neighbor operates a  node that is part of such a network and the antennas look a little bit unusual.

These networks are usually well documented and often you can find [maps](https://freifunk.net/en/how-to-join/find-your-nearest-community/) and [information](https://freifunk.net/en/what-is-it-about/) online.

Google also has a number of pictures of typical antennas that vary in size and number:

[image]
[image]